# Output not printing to standard output after reading from a file, in C using printf ("%s", <a char* variable>);

Tags: c, string, printf

In a C program in Windows, I am reading from a file after creating the file and nothing is printing to the screen, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void readfileforunit1(char *param1)
{
    char *concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
    {
        char *result;
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s%s", str1, str2);
        return result;
    }

    char *exten = ".txt";
    char *theFileName = concat(param1, exten);

    char *strPtr;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen(theFileName, "r");
    fscanf(fptr, "%[^\n]", strPtr);

    printf("Here is the text from the file using char* str:\n%s", strPtr); /*This is where the
                                                                             problem is, it is supposed to print 123456, 555.23*/
}

void structTest(char *param1, double param2)
{
    char *concat(const char *str1, const char *str2)
    {
        char *result;
        __mingw_asprintf(&result, "%s%s", str1, str2);
        return result;
    }

    typedef struct
    {
        char *doc;
        double value;
    } Unit;

    Unit justThis = {param1, param2};

    char *exten = ".txt";
    char *theFileName = concat(justThis.doc, exten);

    FILE *outPutFile = fopen(theFileName, "w");
    fprintf(outPutFile, "%s,%f", justThis.doc, justThis.value);
    fclose(outPutFile);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    structTest("123456", 555.23);

    readfileforunit1("123456");
}
```

I basically create a .txt file with the Unit struct's instance's info in it (the file's name is the instance's doc value) and then I want to read it and print it to standard output, which in this case is the screen. It is supposed to print 123456,555.23 to the screen.

Comment: change `*strPtr`  to `strPtr[100]` or any size big enough to contain the first line of the file or as per your wish - then it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you... this fixed the issue and it works now... why does *strPtr not work?

Comment: And do I see a nested function in this C code?

Comment: @ Agrudge, yes, there is a nested function here but I was just lazy I guess... are nested functions bad?

Comment: Because *strPtr is just a pointer and doesn't have any space where the content from file could be copied. `strPtr[100]` is also a `char *` but that does have some space to contain the data from file.

Comment: @Mr.Green Nested functions are a non-standard, compiler specific extension.

Comment: A string is not just a pointer to a character. It is a sequence of `char` values that is referred to by a pointer to the first character.

Comment: Also, to not overflow the buffer, say `strPtr[100]`, one should specify a maximum length to `fscanf`, "%99[^\n]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from

```
char * strPtr;
```

This makes a character pointer with no allocated space. To read from a file, usually a buffer is used. Two ways,

1. Using char array (as mentioned in comments by @agrudge-amicus

   `char strPtr[SIZE]`
2. Using Malloc to dynamically allocate memory

   ```
   char *strPtr;
   strPtr = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
   ```

Note: Define SIZE according to your file.

Comment: **NO!** Returning the address of an automatic array will cause a memory leak, because the whole array will reach end of life when the function will return. You should only return pointers to static or allocated arrays.